# How do I mount and open flash drive

Tags: mount, 16.04, usb-drive

I cannot open USB drives

I have two USB drives, and when I insert them they show up as

```
contents :ISO 9660 (version Joliet Extension) — Not Mounted`
```

and

```
contents: FAT (32-bit version) — Not Mounted
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to mount USB drives using any file manager by simply clicking on it

or in command-line with the mount command: for that you would need to know where it is in /dev/ - easy way to find out: disconnect USB drive, type ls /dev/, connect it again, type the same command and see what changed, 
Let's suppose it was sdb and sdb1:
Type mkdir /media//USB
Then type sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /media//USB